# How can I display/hide images with html/css/jquery/bootstrap and without empty space or misalignment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display 6 images (3 images on row 1 and 3 on row 2) on a page on which I am using the Bootstrap grid. Images can be filtered via isotope (e.g. a click on isotope value "marine" will show images related to marine). 
I want to show only 3 images and, upon a click on a "See more" button, show the 3 remaining images. Images should be perfectly aligned (they are when I show all 6 images). When the 3 images are hidden, I don't want them to take space. The "see more" button should be right before the first row of 3 images.

I read that I should be using the display:none css property but this still takes up some space.

Can someone help me achieve this please?

Many thanks in advance!

```js
$('.see-more').on('click', function() {
  if ($(document.querySelectorAll('#batch2')).hasClass('d-none')) {
    $(document.querySelectorAll('#batch2')).removeClass('d-none');
  } else {
    $(document.querySelectorAll('#batch2')).css('display', 'none');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- isotope -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <ul id="homepage-list-filters">
      <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li>
      <li data-filter=".feminity">Feminity</li>
      <li data-filter=".marine">Marine species</li>
      <li data-filter=".life">Life moments</li>
      <li data-filter=".humor">Humor</li>
      <li data-filter=".politics">French politics</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- images -->
<div class="row homepage-list-container">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 homepage-list-item feminity">
    <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="homepage-item-info">
      <h4>Eva</h4>
      <a class="homepage-item-seedetails" title="See details">
        <i class="fas fa-info homepage-item-seedetails-CTA"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 homepage-list-item politics">
    <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="homepage-item-info">
      <h4>François M.</h4>
      <a class="homepage-item-seedetails" title="See details">
        <i class="fas fa-info homepage-item-seedetails-CTA"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 homepage-list-item feminity">
    <img src="assets/img/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="homepage-item-info">
      <h4>Clemence</h4>
      <a class="homepage-item-seedetails" title="See details">
        <i class="fas fa-info homepage-item-seedetails-CTA"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Line 2: Shown on click on See More -->
  <div id="batch2" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 homepage-list-item humor">
    <img src="assets/img/4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="homepage-item-info">
      <h4>Edmond</h4>
      <a class="homepage-item-seedetails" title="See details">
        <i class="fas fa-info homepage-item-seedetails-CTA"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="batch2" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 homepage-list-item politics">
    <img src="assets/img/5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="homepage-item-info">
      <h4>François</h4>
      <a class="homepage-item-seedetails" title="See details">
        <i class="fas fa-info homepage-item-seedetails-CTA"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="batch2" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 homepage-list-item marine">
    <img src="assets/img/6.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="homepage-item-info">
      <h4>Léon</h4>
      <a class="homepage-item-seedetails" title="See details">
        <i class="fas fa-info homepage-item-seedetails-CTA"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- See more button -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="see-more">See more</button>
      <button class="see-less hidden">See less</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of `.css('display', 'none');` use `.addClass('d-none');`, since your code depends on the presence or absence of that class. Or, remove the `if`/`else` and replace it with `$('#batch2').toggleClass('d-none');`

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this could help you doing your thing. Just use the `d-none` class from Bootstrap, it is already there.

```js
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("img");

function filter(category) {
  Array.from(images).forEach(image => {
    if (category === null || image.dataset.category === category) {
      image.parentElement.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
      image.parentElement.classList.add("d-none");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.img {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onclick="filter(null)">all</button>
<button onclick="filter('marine')">marine</button>
<button onclick="filter('life')">life</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4"><div class="img" data-category="marine">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div class="img" data-category="life">2</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div class="img" data-category="marine">3</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div class="img" data-category="life">4</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div class="img" data-category="life">5</div></div>
  <div class="col-4"><div class="img" data-category="life">6</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Actually I had the filter buttons work correctly but I am having trouble with the "See more" button. On page load, I want to see divs 1,2,3 only and the "See more" button just below these divs. On click on "See more", I have to see divs 1,2,3,4,5,6 and the "See more" button below divs 4,5,6. On another click on "See more" I want divs 4,5,6 to disappear and the "See more" button to be just below divs 1,2,3

Comment: @balzclr so you want to toggle display of 3 first items / all items, keeping your buttons below the ones displayed at any time ?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, what you can do is add `display: none;` for not displaying objects, and `display: block` to redisplay them.